# Qlikview fails to reload on server when executing stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g, qlikview

I cannot seem to figure out this issue. I have a qlikview document that pulls in a bunch of data and aggregates/joins it up. Typical qlikview stuff. At the end of my process I have an oracle stored procedure call. I am not retrieving anything back. This is a simple call to a database to trigger a process. I have setup my ODBC connection and User DSN on my local machine for the connection. When I run my qvw file on my local machine everything works just fine. The proc call is made and the script executes without any errors.

However, when I put the document on our reload server and after I setup a reload task for it the process throws a general script error when the sql proc is called. What could cause this? The user running the document has execute permissions. Do I need to setup a DSN on the reload server?

Really not sure at all here. Hopefully someone here can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Commenting on my own question in case someone experiences the same error and comes here they will at least have some info. I was dropping a file to an external location. The user for the reload server did not have proper permissions to drop this file at the location. This was the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately QlikView's SQL error messages are not that helpful for debugging purposes. In this case you can try turning on ODBC logging (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/274551) and then reload the script to try and capture the cause of the error.

Finally, if your script refers to a "local" DSN then this also needs to be present on the machine that will perform the reload, in this case the QlikView server.

Comment: I appreciate it. I have investigated the error extensively and it turns out where I was dropping the file the user for the reload server did not have proper permissions. Thanks for any help.